# Primefaces MenuItem actionListener not called

Tags: jsf, primefaces, menuitem

I am using JSF 2.2 and Primefaces 4.0.
I want to fire an actionListener when the menuItem "userSettingMenuItem" is called.
The Problem is that the listener method is never called.

Here is my MenuBar.xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <ui:composition>
    <h:form>
        <p:menubar styleClass="affaires"
            style="position: absolute !important; bottom: 0px !important; vertical-align: bottom !important; list-style: none; width: 100%; text-align: center;">
            <p:menuitem value="#{msg['navigation_home']}" url="home.xhtml" />

            <p:menuitem value="Companies" url="companies.xhtml" />

            <p:menuitem id="messageNumber"
                value="#{taskboxMessageNumberBean.unSeenMessages} #{msg['navigation_taskbox']}"
                url="taskbox.xhtml" />

            <p:menuitem id="userSettingMenuItem"
                        value="#{loginBean.user.USER_NAME}"
                        url="user-settings.xhtml"
                        actionListener="#{userSettingBean.onClickSettingsMenuBar}"/>

            <p:submenu label="#{msg['navigation_admin']}">
                <p:menuitem value="Users" url="#" />
                <p:menuitem value="Edit Help" url="#" />
                <p:menuitem value="Edit GTC" url="#" />
            </p:submenu>

            <p:menuitem value="#{msg['navigation_help']}" url="#" />

        </p:menubar>
    </h:form>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

and the actionListener method from the UserSettingBean:

```
public void onClickSettingsMenuBar(ActionEvent e){

    log.info("onClickSettingsMenuBar");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot have both `url` and `actionListener` at the same time. Use the `actionListener` and redirect users to `user-settings.xhtml` at the end using something like:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("user-settings.xhtml");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add instead of url or outcome, an action and then actionListener. For instance:

```
action="/user-settings.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"
actionListener="#{userSettingBean.onClickSettingsMenuBar}"
```